# choose from a list <select> item and give it to the handler php

Tags: php, database, select

I use a `<select>` list that gets data from a database.
I need to choose from a list item and give it to the handler calc2.php
but it does not work, because the list between tags `<? php?>`
and i cant assign `<select action="calc2.php" name ="plant">`

how to assign `<select action="calc2.php" name ="plant">`
  when  tags between the `<? php?>`
  and send the selected item via the button `<input type="submit" name="submit_all">`

```
 <fieldset>
        <legend>Медоноси</legend>
<?php
    if($text){ 
        echo "
        <select>
            <option selected>Виберіть рослину зі списку</option>";
    foreach($text as $item){

    echo "
            <option>".$item['plants_name']." ".$item['plants_prod']."</option>";
}
//закриваємо список
echo"</select>";

}

?>


    <form action="calc2.php"name="distance" method="POST">
                <br>Ведіть відстань до медоносу<br>
                <input type="number" min="100" max="2000" step="50" name="distance"><br>


    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>  
        <legend>Бджолородини</legend>
            <form action="calc2.php" name="bees" method="POST">
                Кількість сімей на пасіці<br>
                <input type="number" min="1" max="30" name="amount"><br><br>
                Сила сімей<br>
                <input type="number" min="8" max="24" name="power"><br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit_all"> </form>
    </fieldset>
```

Comment: Are you trying to submit all three forms with the same submit button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to post all info at once keep it in 1 form.
If i understood you correctly this should be the fix.

```
<form action="calc2.php" name="bees" method="POST">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Медоноси</legend>
    <? 
    if($text){ ?>
        <select>
            <option selected>Виберіть рослину зі списку</option>
            <?
            foreach($text as $item){
                ?>
                <option><?=$item['plants_name']." ".$item['plants_prod'];?></option>  
                <?        
             }
             ?>
        </select>   
        <?
    }
    ?>
    <br>Ведіть відстань до медоносу<br>
    <input type="number" min="100" max="2000" step="50" name="distance"><br>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>  
    <legend>Бджолородини</legend>            
    Кількість сімей на пасіці<br>
    <input type="number" min="1" max="30" name="amount"><br><br>
    Сила сімей<br>
    <input type="number" min="8" max="24" name="power"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit_all"> </form>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first `<form>` doesn't close and a `<form>...<form>...</form>` is invalid HTML

The inputs do not have a value attribute

```
<fieldset>
....

    <form action="calc2.php"name="distance" method="POST">
                <br>Ведіть відстань до медоносу<br>
                <input type="number" min="100" max="2000" step="50" name="distance"><br>


    </form> <!-- missing above ! -->

</fieldset>

<fieldset>  
        <legend>Бджолородини</legend>
            <form action="calc2.php" name="bees" method="POST">
                Кількість сімей на пасіці<br>
                <input type="number" min="1" max="30" name="amount"><br><br>
                Сила сімей<br>
                <input type="number" min="8" max="24" name="power"><br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit_all"> 
            </form>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your select under the form

```
<form action="calc2.php" name="bees" method="POST" **id=bees-form**>
```

and use the

> `<select name=plants form="bees-form">`

to assign the select element to the form in order to get the select value through $_POST['plants'] in your calc2 php file.

you can read about it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_form.asp)